# Create subquery using query builder

Tags: php, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm, subquery

I try to convert SQL query (which works fine) in Doctrine query builder but I do not succeed because it contains a sub query

This is my SQL Query :

```
SELECT * 
FROM `navigation` 
WHERE `parent_id` = 
(
     SELECT `id` 
     FROM `navigation` 
     WHERE `parent_id` = 47 
     AND `nav_type`= 'nav'
     AND `published` = 1 
     AND `title` = 'Top'
)
```

And this is what I tried in my Repository :

```
class NavigationRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function test($parentId, $type, $status, $title)
    {
        $subQuery = $this->createQueryBuilder('n2')
            ->select('n2.id')
            ->where('n2.parent = :parent')
            ->andWhere('n2.type = :type')
            ->andWhere('n2.status = :status')
            ->andWhere('n2.title = :title')
            ->setParameter('parent', $parentId)
            ->setParameter('type', $type)
            ->setParameter('status', $status)
            ->setParameter('title', $title)
            ->getDQL();

        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('n');
        $qb
            ->where(
                $qb->expr()->eq('n.parent', '('.$subQuery.')')
            )
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();

        return $qb
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
    }
}
```

But I got this error :

> QueryException: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables
>   does not match number of tokens

Why ? It seems I have the right number of parameter yet...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should call `setParameter()` on `$qb` instead of `$subQuery`. The DQL doesn't contain interpolated parameters, it's just a regular string.

Comment: I don't know what your query does or what your database looks like. You asked about the incorrect number of parameters.

Comment: yes indeed thanks, I update my answer with your solution and I put how I call my query

Comment: Try dumping the SQL query with `->getQuery()->getSql()` and manually check what it generated